# Handling multiple AsyncTask launches

Tags: android

I've  got `AsyncTask` in my `Activity`, when user clicks button, I start an `AsyncTask`:

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch(view.getId()){
        case R.id.btnLogin:
            if(task==null){
                task=new LoginTask(this);
                task.execute();
            }
            break;

        }
    }
```

But if user clicks button **after task is completed**, **I want it to be executed one more  time**. What should I do accomplish this? Should I create new task every time user clicks button? Is it OK to create new instance if task is already running?
Also, **task is static inner class**, in order to handle screen rotation.

Comment: Did you click it again after the completion of the task.If yes what is the result.I think it will not be a problem if you click again after finishing the task

Comment: After I click again task is not null, so nothing is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare task as a class variable.And in the postExecute of AsynchTask make it null.Probably you are done

Answer (score 1):

You can execute your AsyncTask's on an `Executor` using [`executeOnExecutor()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#executeOnExecutor%28java.util.concurrent.Executor,%20Params...%29)

Now the pool of threads by default run in parallel :

> Starting with DONUT, this was changed
>   to a pool of threads allowing multiple
>   tasks to operate in parallel. After
>   HONEYCOMB, it is planned to change
>   this back to a single thread to avoid
>   common application erors

To make sure that the threads are running in a serial fashion please use: `SERIAL_EXECUTOR`.

Misc: :[How to use an Executor](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to run only if previous instances have already finished, then you can use AsyncTask.getStatus(), to only start a new task if the status is AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED.

Answer (score 0):

Don't run it at the same time. Make a queue of the Asynctasks and run one after the other.